# insert a String inside another String

Tags: ios, swift

How can I make this:

`var originalString = "http://name.domain.com/image.jpg"`

becomes this:

`originalString = "http://name.domain.com/image_new.jpg"`

I could not find any document about the new `Range<String.Index>` in Swift.
This is not a problem in Obj-C, but without any reference about `Range`, it suddenly becomes so confusing.

Thanks.

---

Edit:
Well, thanks for these solutions. However, let me give you more details about this question.
After uploading an image to server, it responds back with a `String` link, like above, and the `image name` is a random string.
The server also generates different versions of uploaded image (like Flickr). In order to get these images, I have to append a suffix into image name, it looks like this:

`originalString = "http://image.domain.com/randomName_large.jpg"` or `"http://image.domain.com/randomName_medium.jpg"`

So that's why I need to insert a `String` into another `String`. My solution is find the first `.` by scan the link backwardly and append a suffix before it, but the new `Range<String.Index>` makes it confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some [nice and useful methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW38) on `NSString` that you should be able to use:

```
let originalString: NSString = "http://name.domain.com/image.jpg"

let extension = originalString.pathExtension // "jpg"
let withoutExt = originalString.stringByDeletingPathExtension() // "http://name.domain.com/image"
let imageName = withoutExt.lastPathComponent // "image"
let withoutFilename = withoutExt.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent() // "http://name.domain.com/"

let newString = withoutFilename
  .stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(imageName)_new")
  .stringByAppendingPathExtension(extension)
```

I only typed this into the browser (it's untested) but it should give you an idea...

Answer (score 0):

This *can* be done with String manipulation functions. But what if the string 
is

```
var originalString = "http://images.domain.com/image.jpg"
```

? You probably do not want to replace the first or all occurrences of the string
"image" here.

A better tool for this purpose might be `NSURLComponents`, which lets you
modify all components of a URL separately:

```
var originalString = "http://name.domain.com/image.jpg"
let urlComps = NSURLComponents(string: originalString)!
urlComps.path = "/image_new.jpg"
originalString = urlComps.URL!.absoluteString!

println(originalString) // http://name.domain.com/image_new.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using string interpolation?

```
var imageName = "image_new"
originalString = "http://images.domain.com/\(imageName).jpg"
```

Comment: Because I don't have the image name. It's responded back from server. Please check my updated question.